# Find the connection pool hibernate is using

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0

How can I find the connection pool hibernate is using at runtime without looking at the hibernate configuration? 
Is there a API like "getConnectionPoolUsed()" which returns the connection pool hibernate is using?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the source code?

Comment: No I haven't looked at hibernate source code. But is there a API which gives the connection pool hibernate is using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use *C3P0ConnectionProvider* you need *hibernate-c3p0.jar* (available [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-c3p0/4.0.0.CR2))

Then configure the following properties in *hibernate.cfg.xml*

```
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>

    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
```

There is no need to specify *hibernate.connection.provider_class*, Hibernate will use C3P0 as long as there is any *hibernate.c3p0.x* property.

The values are just an example, you should use the configuration most appropriate for your needs.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot find any such method in the javadocs.  And I cannot find any exposed methods that return a `ConnectionProvider`.  (There are some deprecated methods, and some methods on "internal" classes, but you shouldn't be using those.)

IMO, the clean solution is to look at the configuration.

Comment: I have dependency on c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar for my project and I'm using Hibernate 4.2.  However when I set the porperty  
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property> 
I get exception "org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]"   

What is the connectionProvider I should set in the hibernate config file?

Answer (score 0):

No there is no such API.  You could do it using reflection (but that would go too deep for this answer).

Maybe you should ask yourself why you want this.

Comment: I have dependency on c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar for my project and I'm using Hibernate 4.2. However when I set the porperty <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0Connecti‌​onProvider</property> in hibernate.cfg.xml I get exception "org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]"      
What is the connectionProvider I should set in the hibernate config file?

Comment: put a breakpoint at the point where it crashes and check what's wrong.  I'm guessing a version conflict